# Conditional (content-based) routing on Kafka headers in Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I'm using Spring Cloud Stream 3.x in Spring Boot 2.x application to consume messages from a Kafka topic.

I want to have a listener that consumes messages conditionally on some custom header value, as per [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.0.10.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_using_streamlistener_for_content_based_routing):

```
@StreamListener(value = "someTopic", condition = "headers['SomeHeader']=='SomeHeaderValue'")
public void onMessage(Message<?> message) {
  LOGGER.info("Received: {}", message);
}
```

However listener never gets notified, and if condition is removed I see the following in the log:

```
Received: ... SomeHeader: [B@1055e4af ...
```

It turns out that custom headers are left in Kafka byte array raw format, making them not eligible for condition evaluation.

Is some additional configuration needed or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging in sources and stackoveflow I have found the following:

- Spring Cloud Stream delegates to Spring Kafka message and headers conversion ([KafkaMessageChannelBinder](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/blob/master/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/kafka/KafkaMessageChannelBinder.java) ~ getHeaderMapper)
- Headers are left in raw format by default headers conversion implementation ([BinderHeaderMapper](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/blob/master/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/kafka/BinderHeaderMapper.java))
- Spring Cloud Stream allows customization of headers mapping and particularly conversion of headers from byte array to String ([How can I map incoming headers as String instead of byte[] in my Spring Cloud Stream project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58568209))

So I added my custom header mapper bean (bean name is important, it allows to omit additional configuration property), which maps my custom header to String:

```
@Bean
public KafkaHeaderMapper kafkaBinderHeaderMapper() {
    SimpleKafkaHeaderMapper headerMapper = new SimpleKafkaHeaderMapper();
    headerMapper.setRawMappedHeaders(Map.of(
        "SomeHeader", true
    ));
    return headerMapper;
}
```

That fixed the problem:

```
Received: ... SomeHeader: SomeHeaderValue ...
```

P.S. It seems like a bug in Spring Cloud Stream:

1. It introduces its own implementation of header mapper (BinderHeaderMapper), but the latter doesn't respect conditional routing feature.
2. Header mapper is subclassed in KafkaMessageChannelBinder, this added behaviour is non-obvious and will be lost if custom header mapper is provided.

Comment: You should "accept" your own answer. You could also use `condition = "new String(headers['SomeHeader'])=='SomeHeaderValue'"`

Comment: Yep, I can accept it in two days :)
As for `new String` in condition -- usable and shortest solution, but IMHO a bit ugly.

Comment: BTW @GaryRussell what do you think of the points in p.s.?

Comment: I don't remember why we had to reintroduce that mapper but `setRawMappedHeaders` is on the `AbstractKafkaHeaderMapper` so it's available on the `BinderHeaderMapper` too.